# Getting org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "." in JPA

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I am getting this below error.

```
2018-08-01 20:32:29.330[0;39m [33m WARN[0;39m [35m11960[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-9092-exec-5][0;39m [36mo.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42601
[2m2018-08-01 20:32:29.330[0;39m [31mERROR[0;39m [35m11960[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-9092-exec-5][0;39m [36mo.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m ERROR: syntax error at or near "."
  Position: 16
[2m2018-08-01 20:32:29.347[0;39m [31mERROR[0;39m [35m11960[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-9092-exec-5][0;39m [36mo.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet] with root cause

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "."
  Position: 16
```

I want to return a custom object of count as below in repository interface.

```
@Query(value="SELECT " +
        "   new com.telenor.wipro.logging.jpa.entity.setTPSEntities(COUNT(distinct gu_id), service_name) "
        + "FROM fuse_logs WHERE GROUP BY service_name",nativeQuery=true)
public List<FuseTPS> findByTPS();
```

Please help.

Comment: If your generated SQL has a syntax error then perhaps you ought to POST the SQL that is being executed by your JPA provider. It is in the JPA providers log ALWAYS

Comment: Your `setTPSEntities` looks weird. THis sounds like a method name and not an Entity Class Name. POst your Code of this Entity please.